# Find the process echo log

Tags: macos

I find a log file in ~/Library/logs, its name is "kcptun_client.log". I don't know it exactly, but it output the same error log every 10 seconds, which last for about two months! I can't stand it.
How to find the process that output the log and kill it ?

I used `$ lsof ~/Library/Logs/kcptun_client.log`, it echoes nothing

the file is like below

```
2017/09/10 12:20:26 open kcptun-config.json: no such file or directory
2017/09/10 12:20:36 open kcptun-config.json: no such file or directory
2017/09/10 12:20:46 open kcptun-config.json: no such file or directory
2017/09/10 12:20:56 open kcptun-config.json: no such file or directory
2017/09/10 12:21:06 open kcptun-config.json: no such file or directory
2017/09/10 12:21:16 open kcptun-config.json: no such file or directory
2017/09/10 12:21:26 open kcptun-config.json: no such file or directory
2017/09/10 12:21:36 open kcptun-config.json: no such file or directory
2017/09/10 12:21:46 open kcptun-config.json: no such file or directory
2017/09/10 12:21:56 open kcptun-config.json: no such file or directory
2017/09/10 12:22:06 open kcptun-config.json: no such file or directory
2017/09/10 12:22:16 open kcptun-config.json: no such file or directory
2017/09/10 12:22:26 open kcptun-config.json: no such file or directory
2017/09/10 12:22:36 open kcptun-config.json: no such file or directory
2017/09/10 12:22:46 open kcptun-config.json: no such file or directory
2017/09/10 12:22:56 open kcptun-config.json: no such file or directory
2017/09/10 12:23:06 open kcptun-config.json: no such file or directory
2017/09/10 12:23:16 open kcptun-config.json: no such file or directory
2017/09/10 12:23:26 open kcptun-config.json: no such file or directory
2017/09/10 12:23:36 open kcptun-config.json: no such file or directory
2017/09/10 12:23:46 open kcptun-config.json: no such file or directory
2017/09/10 12:23:56 open kcptun-config.json: no such file or directory
2017/09/10 12:24:06 open kcptun-config.json: no such file or directory
```

Comment: Do you use "KCP tunnel"?  Because that's what that log is from.  https://github.com/xtaci/kcptun

Comment: I finally find it. I download an app, it used kcp tunnel, I killed all process one by one then fixed it.